# python seach file in directory - unable to open file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have file list:

```
import os
import fnmatch
files_template = ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt','d.txt','e.txt','f.txt']
dir_path = '/users/john'
```

I need to open file specified in "files_template" list and parse its data but I am able to open the file

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        if file in files_template:
            with open(file, 'r') as fh:
                str = fh.read()
                print(str)
```

I am getting below error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    with open(file, 'r') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.txt'
```

how to fix it?

Comment: it partial answers. I am still not sure what code i need to fix it.

Comment: The second option in the accepted answer. It's a duplicate. You just need to play with it to understand how

Comment: works Thank you so much

Comment: Feel free to close your question if you agree on the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
abs_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
with open(abs_file_path, 'r') as fh:
    ...
```